# Newbie need help understanding java code

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm very new to the java programming language and I would really like some help understanding what the following code is doing. I have a pretty decent understanding of what is going on within the Main class. My problem is what part "this._" plays within the code. How exactly are the names getting transferred? This is not homework just self study. The exercise can be found here:http://www.learnjavaonline.org/Functions Also, suggested reading would be great! Thanks!

```
class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public void printFullName(){
        System.out.println(this.firstName+" "+this.lastname);
  }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[] {
            new Student("Morgan", "Freeman"),
            new Student("Brad", "Pitt"),
            new Student("Kevin", "Spacey"),
        };
        for (Student s : students) {
            s.printFullName();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read a very basic tutorial.. It'll help you very much.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in a debugger.  Learning how to use a debugger will save you many frustrating hours trying to work out why a program doesn't do what you expect.  The sooner you learn how to use it in your IDE the better.

Comment: I would recommend the Java tutorials from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
Also: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/Objects

Comment: Maybe read something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Comment: Not a very good tutorial. We call those things **methods** in Java, not "functions".

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm looking at the suggested reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `this` is used is because the variables `firstName` and `lastName` are shadowed by the constructor parameters. See the differences with `this`:

```
class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Compared to without `this`:

```
class Student {
    private String myFirstName;
    private String myLastName;
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        myFirstName = firstName;
        myLastName = lastName;
}
```

You use `this` to reference variables in the current object.

Comment: Awesome! I still need to do some more reading but seeing it without the "this._" helped a lot. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

`this` references to the object your is working in.

so in your sample

```
class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public void printFullName(){
        System.out.println(this.firstName+" "+this.lastname);
  }
}
```

`this.firstName` is the `private String firstName;` value in your object/class
and `firstName` is the method parameter.

the `this` is required in this example as it otherwise would be `firstName = firstName` and that would assign the value of your parameter to itself.

Answer (score 0):

See that variables with "this" are in **constructor**. This means THE OBJECT, so in the lines:

```
public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
```

you assing variable to your object. Remember that these variables are in **constructor** !